# Terminology for the restriction of the product of two morphisms to its image

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two objects of a category with products and let $p_1: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_1$ and $p_2: X_1 \times X_2 \to X_2$ be the projections.
Given two morphisms $f_1: X \to X_1$ and $f_2: X \to X_2$, the *product* of $f_1$ and $f_2$ is the unique morphism $f:X \to X_1 \times X_2$ such that $p_1 \circ f = p_2 \circ f$.

**Question**. In a category where this makes sense (like monoids, groups, etc.), is there a specific name for the restriction of $f$ to its image (which is a submonoid, subgroup, etc. of $X_1 \times X_2$)?

P.S. At the moment, I am using the term *restricted product*, but I wonder if there is a better term.

Comment: Yes, I mean image, sorry. I will edit my question.

Comment: You mean restricting the codomain of $f$? There are notions of factorisation systems, for example a (regular epi, mono) factorisation, which allows you to write $f$ as a regular epi  ('surjective map onto its image') followed by a mono ('inclusion of its image').

Comment: Just to clarify terminology: the unique morphism into $X_1 \times X_2$ is usually called the *pairing* of $f_1$ and $f_2$ and denoted $(f_1, f_2)$. The *product* of $f_1$ and $f_2$ is the morphism $f_1 \times f_2 : X \times X \to X_1 \times X_2$ defined componentwise.

Comment: @varkor For the *product of $f_1$ and $f_2$*, I followed the terminology given in the wikipedia entry [Product (category theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: ah, it seems this terminology is a little ambiguous, in that case: this issue is mentioned in [this other math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2551654/105106). Something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is a quite special construction to have a particular name, and there is none that would be widely recognized.